# Product of two input numbers ( TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str')

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=input('user enters the first number')
b=input('user enters the second number')
print(a*b)
```

when I finally print out the product of a*b it gives me an error

```
(TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str')
```

any idea how I can sort out this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python3 `input()` always returns a string. You want to multiply the integer values of the strings

Change both a and b to strings and your code will work:

```
a = int(input('user enters the first number'))
b = int(input('user enters the second number'))

print(a*b)
```